# Session variable gets lost after a redirect from ashx to aspx

Tags: asp.net

I have two asp.net website projects, say Website1 and Website2. Website2 is actually a directory under Website1 but they are set up as two different websites for the developers.

Website1 and Website2 use two different databases (say DB1 and DB2 respectively).

I need to retrieve the data from an entire table from DB2, get it to Website1 and show the results on a page (Results.aspx) in Website1. The way I am doing it is, I am getting the data in Website2 in an ashx file, putting it in a Session variable and then redirecting to Results.aspx. But in Results.aspx, the Session variable does not have any data.

I researched and found the possible reasons why this could happen and took care of them, but nothing improved. The relevant code is below:

errorLog.ashx (in Website2)

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="errorLog" %>

Imports System.Data

Public Class errorLog : Implements IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState

   Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim filePath As String = "/admin/Results.aspx" 'file in Website1
        Dim dt As DataTable = ErrorLogData.GetData().Tables(0) 'get data
        context.Session("GAErrorLogs") = dt 'put in Session
        context.Response.Redirect(ServerVariables.GetURL(filePath), False) 'redirect to Website1
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Results.aspx (in Website1)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(Session("GAErrorLogs"), DataTable)  'Session is nothing       
End Sub
```

Once again, this is not cross domain because Website2 resides under Website1 in production. Although I can't test it locally, I am testing it on the test server that has the same directory structure as production.

Can anybody please point out what is going wrong?

Comment: In IIS, 2 applications cannot share session.  Can you convert website2 from application to virtual directory?  If you can't, you'll have to save session (within website1) somewhere (like db), pass a parameter (like guid) and read session from website2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Daniel Blais. Could you elaborate a little bit on how to go for the route you mentioned? I need to read the value of Session in Website1 created in Website2.